# Windows 10 crashes after going to sleep/hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bsod, sleep

I'm experiencing an issue where after I put my PC to sleep or hibernate, the monitor turns off and, after a certain period of time, crashes. This issue doesn't always happen though - for the first few hours after booting, I can put my PC to sleep/hibernate just fine. It's only after a certain time does this issue occur. This is a hardware crash as a dump file is created. This issue has evolved since I tried to solve it, so there will be two crash dumps here for reference.

The first dump file was the following:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffd50f008a22f0, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff8076c6f4850, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffd50f076f7de0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.Sec
    Value: 2

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on CYGNI

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.Sec
    Value: 1

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 80

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.InsufficientDumpfileSize
    Value: 1


DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0xc
  Insufficient Dumpfile Size
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

BUGCHECK_CODE:  9f

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffd50f008a22f0

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff8076c6f4850

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffd50f076f7de0

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff8076b260000 pci

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff807`6c6f4818 fffff807`665637a7 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffd50f`008a22f0 fffff807`6c6f4850 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff807`6c6f4820 fffff807`665636c1 : ffffd50f`246a6d70 00000000`00000000 ffffd50f`1b4a41f0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xdf
fffff807`6c6f4890 fffff807`6628bbd2 : ffffd50f`246a6da8 fffff807`641c9180 fffff807`641c9180 00000000`00000002 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x31
fffff807`6c6f48e0 fffff807`6628ac4d : 00000000`00000000 fffff807`662d9485 00000000`00140001 00000000`000a5e26 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0x172
fffff807`6c6f49d0 fffff807`6640059e : 00000000`00000000 fffff807`641c9180 fffff807`66d27a00 ffffd50f`2112e440 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x5dd
fffff807`6c6f4c60 00000000`00000000 : fffff807`6c6f5000 fffff807`6c6ef000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x9e


IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.19041.2728

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_rt640x64_IMAGE_pci.sys

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {2ce71122-4407-ac30-726e-512dc09f0103}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

After running !devstack:

```
0: kd> !devstack ffffd50f008a22f0
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffd50f050c8050 Unable to load image rt640x64.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for rt640x64.sys
 \Driver\rt640x64   ffffd50f050c81a0  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffd50f050c8020

> ffffd50f008a22f0  \Driver\pci        ffffd50f008a2440  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffd50f008a2c30 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_E0001458&REV_0C\01000000684CE00000"
  ServiceName is "rt640x64"
```

From the device ID and vendor ID, this is a Realtek PCIe Gigabit Ethernet adapter. So I disabled it, but now it's my GPU:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffd68fa3676120, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff806820f4850, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffd68fadb688d0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.Sec
    Value: 2

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on Desktop

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.Sec
    Value: 3

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 85

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.InsufficientDumpfileSize
    Value: 1


DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0xc
  Insufficient Dumpfile Size
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

BUGCHECK_CODE:  9f

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffd68fa3676120

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff806820f4850

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffd68fadb688d0

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80680e60000 pci

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff806`820f4818 fffff806`7c7637a7 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffd68f`a3676120 fffff806`820f4850 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff806`820f4820 fffff806`7c7636c1 : ffffd68f`b5ab72d0 ffffd68f`c4781080 00000000`00000000 00000000`0022d693 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xdf
fffff806`820f4890 fffff806`7c48bbd2 : ffffd68f`b5ab7308 fffff806`79cff180 fffff806`820f4b18 00000000`00000000 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x31
fffff806`820f48e0 fffff806`7c48ac4d : 00000000`00000000 fffff806`7c4d9485 00000000`00140001 00000000`0022d693 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0x172
fffff806`820f49d0 fffff806`7c60059e : 00000000`00000000 fffff806`79cff180 fffff806`7cf27a00 ffffd68f`ad1a5040 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x5dd
fffff806`820f4c60 00000000`00000000 : fffff806`820f5000 fffff806`820ef000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x9e


IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.19041.2728

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_nvlddmkm_IMAGE_pci.sys

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {5337281a-2de3-9ebb-5277-3f179de9b48f}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

```
0: kd> !devstack ffffd68fa3676120
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffd68fa7164030 Unable to load image nvlddmkm.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys
 \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffffd68fa7164180  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffd68fa7164000

> ffffd68fa3676120  \Driver\pci        ffffd68fa3676270  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffd68fa3676a60 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_2187&SUBSYS_87671043&REV_A1\4&1c3d25bb&0&0019"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"
```

I have tried the following:

1. Windows update to 22H2
2. Windows DISM.exe and sfc /scannow
3. Doing an in-place upgrade from an ISO
4. DDU'ing my GPU drivers and reinstalling
5. Changing Link State Power Management to "Moderate Powersavings"
6. Ensuring all devices in device manager can be turned off by Windows

Comment: If you won't get any answers here you can also try these forums intended for BSOD / dump analysis: [tenforums.com](https://www.tenforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/), [bleepingcomputer.com](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/f/233/windows-crashes-and-blue-screen-of-death-bsod-help-and-support/). You can also try [forums.tomshardware.com](https://forums.tomshardware.com/), but it doesn't have its own BSOD section like the other forums.

Comment: @rd51 Thanks, I will give it a shot if I don't have any luck here. John, what are "power drivers"?

Comment: @John It's a custom-built desktop

Comment: @John Thanks for suggesting to update my BIOS! Now my PC gets a BSOD every time I boot, even in safe mode. I had a fine, if slightly buggy PC, but now I don't have any PC at all!

Comment: @John I rolled back the BIOS to the version I had. No luck. No idea why you even recommended to update the BIOS anyways.

Comment: @John So without even figuring out what the issue is or providing further instructions, you just suggest updating the BIOS knowing full well it can exacerbate or even completely brick someone's computer. Then you have the gall to just say "yeah go to a local shop to get it fixed". I previously had at least a functional PC, but now at best I'm out on two RAM sticks (not cheap), or the motherboard at worst. I've had to reset Windows 3 times because the BSODs caused it to corrupt. Either don't reply with a "solution" at all, or figure out what the root cause is first.

Comment: We cannot look over your shoulder or access your PC, so we use the information we have at hand to formulate a recommendation. It was not until after that you said it was a custom built PC.  You should know for your own computer if a BIOS update is safe. So given all that, you need to see a repair shop to see if they can fix it.

Comment: So then why did you suggest a BIOS update before even knowing if it was a custom built PC? It's not my job to know - I'm asking for a reason. If I knew that it would fix it I wouldn't have asked earlier. I'm asking here because I don't have a repair shop near me, nor do I feel comfortable giving my PC to one. So again, you should be asking more questions to figure out what the issue is instead of just throwing out a general solution because it helped you before. Thanks for the broken computer!

Comment: Hibernation depends on BIOS. The great majority of Hibernation issues can be improved and / or repaired with a BIOS update. That is completely normal and I have seen this more than once at customer computers. I was not in any way throwing out an aimless solution.  If you need a service to ask multiple questions for which you may or may not know the answer, then this is probably not the correct forum for you.  By all means flag a moderator and get another opinion. I regret your situation but you also best responsibility for knowing what you can and cannot do with your PC

Comment: My issue isn't with hibernate, it's with sleep. If you took the time to read the question you would've seen that the primary issue was sleep, hibernate just happened to also be a problem.